# How to get android:id="@android:id/tabhost" in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have following xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

I'm using [Android SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library.
There is `mPanelLayout.setDragView(this.findViewById(R.id.???));` that I should set it with id of tab host.

I could set it like `mPanelLayout.setDragView(this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost));` if I set it in xml like `android:id="@+id/tabhost"`. However, I have no idea how to get `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` in my activity.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use `android.R.id.tabhost` for the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this resource comes from the Android framework (`@android`)
so, you have to get it this way:

`mPanelLayout.setDragView(this.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost));`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mPanelLayout.setDragView(getView().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost));
```

Answer (score 0):

just try one of these

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

or

```
TabHost tabHost= (TabHost)view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost)
```